# ExpressionEngine add class to wrap parameter

Tags: expressionengine

I have entries that contain an image as a channel entry field. I am using the following syntax in my template to generate an alt tag w/ data. The problem I have is that I haven't found a way to add a class attribute to the generated img tag.

```
{info-image wrap="image" class="img-responsive"}
```

outputs

```
<img src="http://secretproject.dev/images/uploads/general/dedication2.jpg" alt="dedication2">
```

where the alt data is the image title.

If I take another approach and write

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="{info-image}" alt="{title}">
```

then the title comes from the entry itself and not the file title.

In summary, I need both class and alt attributes but seem to be stuck with one or the other. Is there a way to achieve this in either syntax? Is there another approach? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the variable pair syntax [as described in the documentation](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/custom_fields.html#id10).

```
{info-image}
<img src="{url}" alt="{title}" class="img-responsive">
{/info-image}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was on that page earlier and missed that section.